# Post compilation, manipulate a string in a .net exe?

Tags: .net, executable

I know any answer to this will probably be extremely hacky. I'm all for that, I like pushing the bounds a little just to see what's possible and learn along the way.

I'm wanting to write a program that manipulates a known exe to alter a string inside it. I currently have this very simple C# program that  is the known exe:

```
using System;

namespace Target {
    class Program {

        public static String str = "TESTSTRING";

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
    }
}
```

After compiling, in a hex editor, I see that the string's first letter is found at byte 1898. It seems to be stored in Unicode from there.

[image: Hex editor screenshot showing string in compiled exe]

A little compiler optimization put the string directly in the `Console.WriteLine` call and seems to be calling some constructor (at least that's what I believe `.cctor` is). I've toyed with other strings of the same length to make sure I knew what everything was. I've written an app that successfully replaces `TESTSTRING` with `XXXXXXXXXX` (note that they're the same length) and run the modified exe. It works great.

However if I try replacing the string with a different length string, the output exe is unrunnable. I've found that the byte immediately before the string seems to contain the length. It seems to be the number of bytes of the unicode string + 1 (I have no idea what the +1 is for, maybe a null terminator?). However, if I replace that length with a proper updated value, it still won't run. There seem to be several bytes after the end of the string that are different for different length strings. My guess is that the constructor is something similar to `new String(...)` and that those other bytes are other parameters to the constructor (the first parameter being a `char[]` or `byte[]` that's preceded with it's length), but I can't come up with an explanation of what the other parameters specifically are.

I know I'm breaking things usually left alone, but I'm curious about the possibility. What do I not know about the structure of a .Net exe that knowing would enable me to do this? To replace one string in a compiled EXE with another of a different length? Also how do I account for strings with lengths longer than 127? Anything longer than that affects how many bytes are needed to store the length of the string.

I want to be able to do this with any arbitrary replacement string. So precompiling a specific string and then just patching the exe with that precompiled string and it's meta data is not an option. I should be able to do this without a decompiler/compiler. I definitely want to do this programmatically, so Reflector is not an option. Can this be reliably done?

Comment: As Lucas writes in his answer, the way to manipulate .Net exe's is to use ILDasm.exe, modify the the IL code, and reassemble with ILAsm.exe. This is sometimes called "round-tripping". I use this myself for various post-build manipulations of my C# programs. Can you explain more of why you don't want to use a decompiler/compiler?

Comment: For example, one of the modifications I do this way is to obfuscate (very simply and primitively) all of the strings in my programs. If you want me to write more details as an answer I can do that.

Comment: Maybe one isn't available. God forbid this kind of hack makes it to a production code kind of environment or a client machine, the presence of a compiler or assembler of any kind is not guaranteed and downloading or including one in the project seems like a lot of extra resources. I could manipulate source code strings all day. This is about a low level challenge I'm setting myself.

Comment: One horrible example that comes to mind of when I might want to do this on a client machine is when using some sort of interpreter in C#. Javascript .Net can run javascript code in a context during a C# runtime (AT runtime, not some sort of javascript compiler) and I was wondering if I could inject javascript into an exe that uses Javascript .Net to run it. It doesn't offer much benefit, but nothing about it seems impossible. It's a challenge for the sake of a challenge to overcome. My current Everest.

Comment: Hmm, but you realize that trying to manipulate exe's on a client machine in a production environment will probably involve problems with file access authorization and/or being flagged as a virus by the resident anti-virus program. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: I doubt it'll ever go anywhere like that. To me, this is like a sudoku puzzle in the newspaper or a Project Euler problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [ildasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1.aspx).  It's not a decompiler but a disassembler. It will produce an MSIL text output you can alter and then recompile with [ilasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/496e4ekx.aspx).

**EDIT:** How could I forget? [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/) should be of **great** interest to you.

---

Some remarks:

- `.cctor` is short for *class constructor* aka the *static constructor*, not the *instance constructor*.
- The internal representation of a string is still null-terminated, that's why you see length + 1 in the file. This is only used for easier interoperability (P/Invoke)
- changing the length and offsetting the bytes doesn't work, since I guess it breaks some other data in the file that stores offsets. You'd have to update every offset stored in the exe to make it work. Which probably means... disassembling it. And that's what ildasm is for.

Comment: What kind of offsets would be screwed up?

Comment: I don't know the PE file format nor the MSIL binary format, but in a binary file you usually can have a lot of offsets. There's at least one offset that's very important: the offset to the entry point of your program. Then, there are offsets between the code and the metadata. You'd have to find a description of the PE format, and the CLR metadata format, and the MSIL format to know them all.

Comment: @Corey I completely forgot about Mono.Cecil - check it out!

Comment: _**TIP:**_ Reassembling with `ilasm` might not work _{{Citation needed}}_ for source code written in `VC++` (I remember failing on unmanaged code years ago! I moved away completely from .net so, not sure if it's still the same!) BTW, I did notice that OP is specifically about `C#` and hence the "TIP". :)

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr yup, it won't work on *mixed-mode* assemblies. If you compile VC++ with `/clr:pure` it should work though, but then there's not much point in using C++/CLI in this mode anyway.